# Arraystring(19) Why isn't it a string and why wont it convert to one

Tags: php

The following code

```
foreach($_POST['queryvars'] as $key=>$value) {
            if(in_array($key,$validnames) && !isset($translation[$key])) {
                try {
                    $runoptions = true;
                    if(in_array($key,$datefields)) {
                        if(isset($_POST['queryvars'][$key.'end'])) {
                            $runoptions = false;
                            $prep->bindParam(":{$key}start",$_POST['queryvars'][$key],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $prep->bindParam(":{$key}end",$_POST['queryvars'][$key.'end'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        }
                    }
                    if($runoptions) {
                        var_dump($key);
                        echo "$key = ";
                        var_dump($_POST['queryvars'][$key]);
                        echo "\n";
                        $prep->bindParam(":$key",$_POST['queryvars'][$key],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception $ex) {
                    echo $querystart." \n" ;
                    echo 'error: "'.$_POST['queryvars'][$key].'"'."\n";
                    echo $ex->getMessage();
                    echo $ex->getTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Throws a weird notice

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\talk\getAllReisFinancieel.php</b> on line <b>147</b><br />
Arraystring(19) "totaalbedragfactuur"
```

The var dump says its an Arraystring, but when I google on array string I can't find a single hit of what an arraystring is.

I've tried making it a "normal" string by `$key = "$key";` but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to solve this or how I can test if the type is ArrayString?

Comment: Why is this tagged as JavaScript when it's just PHP?

Comment: Little derp on my side

Comment: There is no `Arraystring` in php http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php. Maybe it's double print without space between? To convert array to string, use `implode('separator', $array);`

Comment: It's no doubleprint. this is the actual output of explode. I checked it all. It is actually registered as Arraystring. hence my question.

Comment: what do you get when you run `is_array()` or `is_string()` on that variable?  You could do those tests and then convert if needed.